# Incorrect output from simple Caesar Cipher program

Tags: java, arrays

```
class numbers     
{
  int[] code = {1, 3, 5};
  int[] p = {7,0,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  int phone[] = new int[10];

  void getNum()
  {
       for (int i =0; i< p[2]; i++)
       {
          phone[i] = (p[i] + code[0]) % 10;
       }
       for (int i =3; i< p[5]; i++)
       {
          phone[i] = (p[i] + code[1]) % 10;
       }
       for (int i =6; i< p.length; i++)
       {
          phone[i] = (p[i] + code[2]) % 10;
       }
  }
  void displayNum()
  {
        String output = "The resulting phone number is: \n";
        for (int i = 0; i< phone.length; i++)
        {

            output = output + phone[i];

        }
        System.out.println(output);

  }
```

For the above line code, my result should be:

818-456-9012

This is based off the Caesar cipher I'm using that converts my array to a different array.

However, when I run the code, I'm getting the result:

818-234-9012

Please help fix my code. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because StackOverflow only complements, but does not replace, a debugger.

Comment: How do I use a debugger? I'm using Netbeans IDE. I know there is a debugging option, however, there is no actual error/bug in my code. It just isn't attaining the result I expect it to be.

Comment: If there's no error/bug in your code, then why isn't it working as you expect? And Google can tell you how to use Netbean's debugger

Comment: Also, I can see at least three places where you've made mistakes. A debugger would reveal them *really* fast. Question for you: Why did you pick those particular bounds for your `for` loops?

Comment: Hint: You have made the exact _same_ mistake in exactly 3 places

Comment: The debug option hasn't shown me anything except that it built successfully. Those bounds are necessary because the first three numbers are attached to a code, the second three to another and the final 4, attached to the final code.

Comment: Why are you using array elements instead of array indices then? Also, it appears you aren't using the debugger successfully. The debugger is supposed to be used to step through code. The compiler is what tells you if the program built successfully.

Comment: I thought I was using array indexes already. My goal in this problem is to change the array elements via their indexes. As you might know, I'm still pretty new to Java so I may be wrong on that.

Comment: `p[5]` isn't an array index. `5` is the index, `p[5]` is the element at index 5. Same thing with `p[2]`. Now do you see where something's a little off?

Comment: Right, I know that, but how does changing from element to index help?

Comment: What's the element at `p[2]`?

Comment: p[2] should be 7, but after the getNum method, it becomes 8.

Comment: If `p[2] == 7`, then what does `for (int i =0; i< p[2]; i++)` become? (keep going to examples with `5` instead of `2`, my mistake)

Comment: Should become 8, 1, 8

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. If `p[2] == 7`, then `for (int i =0; i< p[2]; i++)` becomes `for (int i =0; i< 7; i++)`, right? Does that look right to you?

Comment: :) yeah it makes sense

Comment: Please STOP and learn how to use the debugger in NetBeans.  The _compiler_ tells you if your program is syntactically correct.  The debugger allows you to step through your code one statement at a time and examine the variable values at each step.  Learning how to do this is a prerequisite for posting any questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JimGarrison do you know any good tutorial about debugging?

Comment: Use your Google-fu.  A hallmark of a good developer is knowing how to find out answers to questions on your own.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out

```
  void getNum()
  {
       for (int i =0; i< 3; i++)
       {
          phone[i] = (p[i] + code[0]) % 10;
       }
       for (int i =3; i< 6; i++)
       {
          phone[i] = (p[i] + code[1]) % 10;
       }
       for (int i =6; i< p.length; i++)
       {
          phone[i] = (p[i] + code[2]) % 10;
       }
  }
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. I understand fully now. Thank you. I was using the array elements rather than the index number even though I was only increasing the array index and not the element itself.

Comment: Sorry buddy but thanks so much for all the effort in teaching me! I'm glad you tried to teach it to me rather than show it to me. It all makes so much more sense now once it's shown.

Comment: @user3580294 what's wrong?

Comment: @KickButtowski I feel quite strongly that this isn't a *good* answer, and should be considered borderline, if not outright, *bad*. While it is correct, it at the very least should explain *what* was wrong and *why* instead of providing something that could very well be copy-pasted with the asker learning nothing from it. I'm glad to see that OP figured out what was wrong from this, but if there were another answer that did exactly this but also explained what changes were made and why, that would be a far better answer.

Comment: @user3580294 If you go through previous comments then you can easily figure out what is the problem. I just thought it would be redundant to explain it again.